# "... is not a symbolic link"

Tags: system-installation, ibus, input-language, pinyin, korean

I tried downloading `ibus-Hangul` by doing the following:
`sudo apt-get update`,  `sudo apt-get install ibus-Hangul`. However, this shows up:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...
"/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.54 is not a symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so.52 is not a symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.54 is not a symbolic link
```

(command prompt returns)

I tried downloading ibus-Hangul before and while I did see the red, yellow, and blue emblem for the language input in the taskbar, I could not type in Hangul nor Hanja. All letters were Latin alphabet.

I tried downloading ibus-Pinyin before and I could not type in Pinyin. All letters were Latin alphabet.

Because I couldn't get it to work, I decided to uninstall and reinstall these files, and the problem above turned up while installing back `ibus-Hangul`.

Comment: This question is a mixture of two things. I'd suggest that you fix the error messages first (see Trent's answer), and then ask a new question about how to type using those IBus packages.

Answer (score 0):

These library errors are most probably not related to your actual problem with the various ibus packages.  Bit of a red herring warning, likely the problem with them is something else.

These 3 libraries are party of an audio/video library, at a guess you've either installed a custom version of it or somehow managed to change them from symbolic links but again I doubt it's the problem.  You could check further into these files like this:
sudo dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.54 
sudo ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.54

This will allow us to see what package (if any) they are from.

As for actually debugging your ibus issues, sadly I have absolutely no idea about that.  Hopefully someone else can help there.  You could maybe check ~/.xsession-errors for any error messages related to using the input when it's not working.

Comment: The result is really long, but this is the beginning: 
`pm-utils: /usr/lib/pm-utils/bin
wine1.6-i386:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/fakedlls/openal32.dll
xdiagnose: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/utils/url_io.py
racket-common: /usr/share/racket/pkgs/redex-benchmark/redex/benchmark/models/rvm/compiled/jdg-grammar_rkt.zo
libfreerdp-plugins-standard:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/freerdp/audin-client-pulse.so
wine1.6-amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine/fakedlls/dmime.dll
linux-headers-4.4.0-45:`